# ASP.NET MVC Windows Authentication refusing to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I've created a MVC Web Application using Visual Studio 2015. My goal is to change the authentication mode from none to Windows Authentication as I need so I can use the @User.Identity.Name method to identify the user. A short summary of what I've tried so far:

### Project Properties

- set Anonymous Authentication: *disabled*
- set Windows Authentication: *enabled*

### Web.config

- adding *maxUrlLength="65536"* attribute to the httpRuntime tag
- adding *maxQueryStringLength="10240"* attribute to the httpRuntime tag
- adding `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` within the `<system.web>` tag
- adding the system.webServer tag (this ends up in a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS whenever I add it):

  ```
  <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
  </system.webServer>
  ```

### Windows

1. In Control Panel open *"Programs and Features"*.
2. Select "*Turn
   Windows features on or off".*
3. Navigate to Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Security and make sure the *Windows authentication node* is checked.

### IIS Express

I tried creating a new project from scratch and neatly selecting Windows Authentication during the setup of the project. This works fine, so I believe **my IISExpress settings are 100% correct**. I even checked the applicationhost.config file and it doesn't have an entry for my specific project. Again, it works just fine if I select the correct authentication when creating a new project.

---

None of the above seems to work and all end up with an IIS error when I try to run the Visual Studio project:

```
HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.
```

This is what the URL looks like in the IIS Error Page:

> http://localhost:52728/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252F

As you can tell I get an infinite redirect loop, and this is probably the reason why I'm unable to get this working. I do however have no idea what is causing it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guess I'm able to answer my own question as I've just got it working. Might come in handy for people who experience similar errors in the future.

**Solution:** I had to comment out the following code in App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    });
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also check C:\Users[Your UserName]\Documents\IISExpress\Logs[Application Name] for any error details or URL used during request.